# Implement universal, lightweight, and unobtrusive tagging of arbitrary objects?

Tags: javascript, delegation

**NB:** *The material in the subsection titled* **Background** *is not essential.  The full description of the question is fully contained in the preceding paragraphs.*

I'd like to implement a universal, lightweight, and "unobtrusive" way to "tag" arbitrary objects.

More specifically, I want to define the equivalent of the (abstract) functions `tag`, `isTagged`, and `getTagged`, such that:

1. `isTagged(t)` is `true` if and only if `t` was the value returned by `tag(o)`, for some object `o`;
2. `getTagged(tag(o))` is identical to `o`, for every object `o`;
3. if `t = tag(o)`, then `tag(t)` should be identical to `t`;
4. with the exception of the behaviors described in (1), (2), and (3) above, and strict identity tests involving `===`, `tag(o)` and `o` should behave the same way.

[EDIT: One further requirement is that the implementation should not modify the `Object` class, nor any other standard class, in any way.]

For example:

```
>>> isTagged(o = "foo")
false
>>> isTagged(t = tag(o))
true
>>> getTagged(t) === o
true
>>> tag(t) === t
true
>>> t.length
3
>>> t.toUpperCase()
"FOO"
```

Below I give my best shot at solving this problem.  It is (almost) universal, but, as it will soon be clear, it is **anything but** lightweight!!!  (Also, it falls rather short of fully satisfying requirement 4 above, so it is not as "unobtrusive" as I'd like.  Moreover, I have serious doubts as to its "semantic correctness".)

This solution consists of wrapping the object `o` to be tagged with a "proxy object" `p`, and copying **all** the properties of `o` (whether "owned" or "inherited") to `p`.

My question is:

> is it possible to achieve the specifications given above without having to copy all the properties of the tagged object?

---

### Background

Here's the implementation alluded to above.  It relies on the utility function `getProperties`, whose definition (FWIW) is given at the very end.

```
function Proxy (o) { this.__obj = o }

function isTagged(t) {
  return t instanceof Proxy;
}

function getTagged(t) {
  return t.__obj;
}

var tag = (function () {
  function _proxy_property(o, pr) {
    return   (typeof pr === "function")
           ? function () { return pr.apply(o, arguments) }
           : pr;
  }

  return function (o) {
    if (isTagged(o)) return o;

    if (typeof o.__obj !== "undefined") {
      throw TypeError('object cannot be proxied ' +
                      '(already has an "__obj" property)');
    }
    var proxy = new Proxy(o);
    var props = getProperties(o); // definition of getProperties given below
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; ++i) {
      proxy[props[i]] = _proxy_property(o, o[props[i]]);
    }
    return proxy;
  }
})();
```

This approach, ham-fisted though it is, at least seems to work:

```
// requirement 1
>>> isTagged(o = "foo")
false
>>> isTagged(p = tag(o))
true

// requirement 2
>>> getTagged(p) === o
true

// requirement 3
>>> tag(p) === p
true

// requirement 4
>>> p.length
3
>>> p.toUpperCase()
"FOO"
```

...well, *almost*; requirement (4) is not always satisfied:

```
>>> o == "foo"
true
>>> p == "foo"
false
>>> o == o
true
>>> p == o
false
```

---

**FWIW**, here's the definition of the function `getProperties`, which is used by the `tag` function.  Criticisms welcome.  (**WARNING:** ***I'm a completely clueless JS noob who doesn't know what he's doing!***  Use this function at your own risk!)

```
function getProperties(o) {
  var seen = {};
  function _properties(obj) {
    var ret = [];
    if (obj === null) {
      return ret;
    }
    try {
      var ps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
    }
    catch (e if e instanceof TypeError &&
                e.message === "obj is not an object") {
      return _properties(obj.constructor);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; ++i) {
      if (typeof seen[ps[i]] === "undefined") {
        ret.push(ps[i]);
        seen[ps[i]] = true;
      }
    }
    return ret.concat(_properties(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));
  }
  return _properties(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating all of this. There's no reason you need to store the tag on the object itself. If you create a separate object that uses the object's pointer as a key, not only will you conserve space, but you'll prevent any unintentional collisions should the arbitrary object happen to have a property named "_tagged".

```
var __tagged = {};

function tag(obj){
    __tagged[obj] = true;
    return obj;
}

function isTagged(obj){
    return __tagged.hasOwnProperty(obj);
}

function getTagged(obj){
    if(isTagged(obj)) return obj;
}
```

== EDIT ==

So I decided to take a minute to create a more robust tagging system. This is what I've created.

```
var tag = {
    _tagged: {},

    add: function(obj, tag){
        var tags = this._tagged[obj] || (this._tagged[obj] = []);
        if(tag) tags.push(tag);
        return obj;
    },

    remove: function(obj, tag){
        if(this.isTagged(obj)){
            if(tag === undefined) delete this._tagged[obj];
            else{
                var idx = this._tagged[obj].indexOf(tag);
                if(idx != -1) this._tagged[obj].splice(idx, 1);
            }
        }
    },

    isTagged: function(obj){
        return this._tagged.hasOwnProperty(obj);
    },

    get: function(tag){
        var objects = this._tagged
          , list = []
        ;//var

        for(var o in objects){
            if(objects.hasOwnProperty(o)){
                if(objects[o].indexOf(tag) != -1) list.push(o);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Not only can you tag an object, but you can actually specify different types of tags and retrieve objects with specific tags in the form of a list. Let me give you an example.

```
var a = 'foo'
  , b = 'bar'
  , c = 'baz'
;//var

tag.add(a);
tag.add(b, 'tag1');
tag.add(c, 'tag1');
tag.add(c, 'tag2');

tag.isTagged(a); // true
tag.isTagged(b); // true
tag.isTagged(c); // true

tag.remove(a);
tag.isTagged(a); // false

tag.get('tag1'); // [b, c]
tag.get('tag2'); // [c]
tag.get('blah'); // []

tag.remove(c, 'tag1');
tag.get('tag1'); // [b]
```

Comment: There's still one reason to store the tag on the object itself: garbage collector.

Comment: That's a good point. If you deleted the object, you would also need to delete it from the collection. One could write a delete function that would make this rather trivial, though.

Answer (score 2):

You're over complicating it :

```
var tag = function(o) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, '__tagged', {
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: "static"
    });
    return o;
}

var isTagged = function(o) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).indexOf('__tagged') > -1;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry: I forgot to mention that the implementation should not modify the standard `Object` class (nor any other standard class) in any way.  I have edited my post to make this additional requirement explicit.  Apologies for my oversight.

Comment: It doesn't modify the standard class, it will only modify the object you're tagging and it will not show when you use `for(var k in o);`